# Unity GetComponent<Type> return value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, gameobject

Which game object of type `Type` is returned from the call

```
GetComponent<Type>();
```

if the calling game object has more than one object of that type attached?

The documentation for this function only says a game object is returned if it exists, else null.

I have a game object with multiple `Collider2D`s and want to know which one would be returned and if it's consistent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If *more than one* Component is attached that matches the specified Type, Unity will return the *first* one. However, do not rely on this, as which one is "first" may not be under your control. It will be deterministic, but may change unexpectedly due to how Unity maintains, serializes, and stores the data internally.

This is why it's generally not recommended that you have more than one of the same type of component (e.g. colliders) attached to the same game object. If you need more than one, use children.

Comment: I think OP knows this, but the question is if two objects exist that implement `T`, which one is returned?

Comment: Thanks for the response! As suggested, I was able to restructure my game object and use a child game object to avoid having multiple components of the same type!